# Differences between the accuracy of the buddy system and hatching eggs

Tags: pokemon-go

Today I decided to test the accuracy of the buddy system, to record the distance traveled compared to the registry of the distance to hatch the eggs and I was a little disappointed with the result.

I put a 2km egg in the incubator and selected the Magikarp as a buddy before leaving on walk.

I walked somewhere close to 3 km without stopping at Pokestops or Pokémon that appeared. At the end of the path, I checked the result in the app to see the recorded distance difference:

[image]

- The egg hatch shows 1.91km walked.
- The Buddy system shows 2.7km walked.

If the systems are the same, as this difference be explained? Is there more precision in Buddy System?

Comment: I'm tempted to close as this is something I would imagine only the developers would really know the answer to.

Comment: I have to agree with @VanBuzzKill it's a great question, that I would also love to know the answer to, but there's no way for anyone here to know currently. Whatever it is I hope it's implemented for eggs soon enough.

Comment: Maybe they update at different times? Try waiting a few minutes and see if the egg catches up.

Comment: In my experience I had the opposite, buddy system showed less while my egg registered further. I'm quite disappointed too, that they can't just use the same distance logic

Comment: @VanBuzzKill I encourage re-opening. Via experimentation and ingenuity, Go players have discerned the methods behind dozens of black-box behaviors. There is no a-priori reason to believe that the community cannot find well-corroborated, reproducible differences in how the eggs and buddies track distance.

Comment: A partial answer in the meantime could include reasons that have been counted *out* as affecting the process, links to experiments that others players have undertaken, and known-good information about how the system generally works (for example: zig-zagging discounts lots of your distance due to delta summation)